# Radiator Leak Overnight?

Tags: radiator

I took my car in to have my AC Compressor replaced.  Well they replaced the AC Compressor, called and told me my vehicle is ready for pickup.  When I got their to pick-it up I see a steady steady constant flow leak of green flowing down.  I pointed it out to the shop, and they said they were sorry and would look into it.

They took about 3 hours and called me back and now said my Radiator had deteriorated.  The radiator had no issue prior to going into the shop, and personally I don't feel that a radiator would deteriorate THAT FAST.  It seems to me that the shop knicked it or dinged it while replacing the AC Compressor.

My question being, can a radiator "deteriorate" THAT MUCH overnight?!?!

EDIT --
There is a crack about 2 inches below the top of the radiator on the inside (not the side facing the wheel well)

EDIT #2
1996 Ford Explorer 6cylinder.  New radiator was put in the vehicle roughly 4 yrs ago.

(working on images)...

Comment: See my answer, it's be updated since you updated yours. Make model year, and a picture would be helpful

Comment: Exactly my thought. A picture would help immensely

Answer (score 4):

I would ask to see where the radiator is leaking. It should be obvious by the source of the leak whether it was physical damage done during the repair or not.

Based on your edit, if the crack is in the core (the metal part in the middle between the two tanks, one on each side.) and there is no signs of physical damage like it's been hit with the end of the tool or something then it's not likely that they caused the leak.

If you will update your question with make model year I can give you more information.

Answer (score 3):

No, "deterioration" doesn't happen overnight. However, I would stop short of suggesting that the shop has damaged the radiator.

It is possible that the shop is referring to some seal, hose or component that is part of the cooling system other than the radiator. Based on the information provided in the question, the most prudent recommendation here would be to ask them to specifically pinpoint the source of the leak.

Comment: see my edit and let me know your thoughts.  Not a house, or a seal.